# Is there a way to undo just a single line in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say I have a file with 100 lines of code in a file. 1-90 is a python class code. 91-100 is some code that uses the class.

```
line 1 - class Test:
line 90 - end of class Test

line 91 - t = Test()
line 92 - input = [1,2,3,4,5]
line 93 - output = t.run(input)
line 94 - print(output)
```

Now I do changes in the following order

- change line 92 ( this breaks the code )
- fix something in the class from line 1 - line 90. The new input works
- To verify the prev input, I need to undo just the line 92. But an undo will undo all the fixes in the file as well.

So I was wondering if there is a way to do it? Or is it asking for too much? As it would have to keep track of all the lines. But if the undo history has a line number already saved in it, I guess this would not be that hard to do.

Comment: What undo are you talking about?

Comment: @TomTom An undo is file-based. So when you undo, any change you make to the file will be undone. I want to just undo a particular line to its previous state, without undoing any other lines that may have been altered

Comment: I am sorry, in every windows editor undo is also in the menu and is actually character / operations based. YOu mean undo on source control level (likely git?) This is not an editor function but provided by source control.

Comment: undo until you get to the previous version of line 92, copy line 92, redo all edits and paste the previous value of line 92. It all depends if the undo buffer is large/deep enough. Other wise use source control or incremental backup to get line 92

Comment: @rioV8 don't you think that is too much work? I mean if the undo history already contains the line number, wouldn't it be more easy to just be able undo just one line?

Comment: the undo is based on the state of the file when the edit was made. You can't undo some random element of the undo history. Most likely the line numbers do not match.

Comment: Not sure if that's possible in VSCode or not but you can do that in Emacs. It's called undo region (selected text or code). You can even undo an undo.